# Replace text in textInput field

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a small app where the user can combine words and data to build a story. I want to be able to find the selected text within the `textInput()` field and replace it with the selection of a `radioGroupButton()` at any place in the text. In the real application, there isn't any "____" section and the user should be able to replace any highlighted text or append to then end if nothing is selected.

[image]

I put together the `action_script` code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430219/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-a-shiny-textareainput/50430316#50430316) but couldn't figure out how to incorporate the info back into the `observeEvent()`

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

replacement_location <-
  'Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("selected_text", function(NULL) {
    var ctl = document.getElementById("phrase");
    var startPos = ctl.selectionStart;
    var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd;
    alert(startPos + ", " + endPos);
  });'


ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(replacement_location)),
    textAreaInput(
      inputId = "phrase",
      label = "I want to replace the selected text", 
      value = "Starts on ___ and ends on ___ of next week."
    ),
    radioGroupButtons(
      "wday",
      NULL,
      c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"),
      selected = ""
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$wday, {
    loc_start <- 10
    loc_end <- 14
    
    new_phrase <- 
      paste0(
        substr(input$phrase, 1, loc_start), 
        input$wday, 
        substr(input$phrase, loc_end, nchar(input$phrase))
      )
    
    updateTextInput(
      session = session,
      "phrase",
      value = new_phrase
    )
    
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "selected_text", message = list(NULL))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution ended up working for me. There are a few changes from the original code:

1. add script for getting ranges via `Shiny.setInputValue()`
2. use `tagAppendAttributes()` for `onmouseup` and `onkeyup` events
3. view changes as selection changes
4. update `textinput` object (`input$phrase`)

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

get_replacement_location <-                                         # (1)
  "Shiny.setInputValue(                                            
    'selected_text', [
      document.getElementById('phrase').selectionStart,
      document.getElementById('phrase').selectionEnd
    ]
  );"

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    textAreaInput(
      inputId = "phrase",
      label = "I want to replace the selected text", 
      value = "Starts on ___ and ends on ___ of next week."
    ) %>% 
      # add event triggers                                           # (2)
      tagAppendAttributes(                                           #
        onmouseup = get_replacement_location,                        #
        onkeyup = get_replacement_location                           #
      ),                                                             #
    radioGroupButtons(
      "wday",
      NULL,
      c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"),
      selected = ""
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # view in console as selected text changes                         # (3)
  observeEvent(input$selected_text, print(input$selected_text))      #
  
  # use info to update the textInput object when buttons are pressed
  observeEvent(input$wday, {
    # now have access to input                                       # (4)
    loc_start <- input$selected_text[1]                              #
    loc_end <- input$selected_text[2]                                #
    # add 1 for string splitting                                     #
    if (loc_start != loc_end)  loc_end <- input$selected_text[2] + 1 #
    
    new_phrase <- 
      paste0(
        substr(input$phrase, 0, loc_start), 
        input$wday, 
        substr(input$phrase, loc_end, nchar(input$phrase))
      )
    
    updateTextInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "phrase",
      value = new_phrase
    )
  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```